# Error installing gem capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby, rubygems, capybara

I am new to ruby, but while trying to install capybara to run test on my system I get the following error. Im running OSX

```
my_app$ gem install capybara-webkit
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capybara-webkit-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capybara-webkit-0.7.2/./gem_make.out
```

here are results from gem_make.out

```
/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

Comment: Can you show what `gem_make.out` file says? I had a problem with installing `capybara-webkit` recently and what helped me was reinstalling `libqt4-dev` package on Ubuntu. Not sure what is equivalent on OSX, but may be you miss some qt dependencies too.

Comment: I am new to rails. I do not know what Qt is, I am looking for it now to install. thanks Marc

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try installing [libqt via homebrew](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit).

```
$ brew install qt@5.5
```

Comment: I'm still getting this same error after installing Qt. Qt itself seems to work fine, I can run the Qt Creator just fine.

Comment: @Francois - please post a separate question with your specific error messages, and reference this question as "not a solution for you" (in addition to your machine-specific details and why it's not working for you) so the community can properly address it.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Post a separate question with your specific error messages, and reference this question as "not a solution" for you.

Comment: Why ask as a separate question? Would be nice to get all the information on this in one place. I to am having the trouble after installing qt

Comment: For those people, who got any error, trying to install qt@5.5 - make sure, that you have checked all the NOTEs for your OS version, following the link. For example: `NOTE: If you got error fatal: reference is not a tree: 9ba3d6ef8891e5c15dbdc9333f857b13711d4e97, use git fetch --unshallow to complete git history.

NOTE: If you get Error: qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion, comment line #25 in Formula/qt@5.5.rb`

Answer (score 92):

Solution for Linux.

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev
```

**Debian Stable**

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

**Fedora**

```
yum install qt-webkit-devel
```

**Fedora 16**

```
yum install qtwebkit-devel
```

This works for me maybe it will be also helpful for somebody.

Comment: `Package qtwebkit-devel-2.2.2-5.fc16.x86_64 already installed and latest version` :(

Comment: @panzi I have the same issue in Ubuntu 12.04 . Were you able to get a fix for it ? Would appreciate any tips..

Comment: @lnreddy I forgot how I fixed it. Sorry. Maybe it was something like running this before the setup: `export QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4`

Comment: No problem , I found it ..My Ubuntu was missing the GNU c++ libraries..the g++ . So, I did `sudo apt-get install g++` and then it worked.

Comment: Nowadays it looks like `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev` works for Ubuntu too.

Comment: Thanks so much. It resolved the issue that I'm encountering

Answer (score 22):

```
brew install qt@5.5
```

and then

```
gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.7.2'
```

-v 0.7.2 is to select version project is asking you to install. See that installing qt from http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Mac_OS_X requires to set PATH variable.

Answer (score 10):

Was having exactly this problem trying to install capybara-webdriver on CentOS 6 after installing QT.

Fixed the problem by adding the following to my PATH environment variable

```
/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/
```

Comment: This totally helped me on my CentOS set up.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I was looking for on CentOS/RHEL. Thanks!

Comment: v1.1.1 asks for at least QT 4.8.0 in CentOS 6.5, just to know. I've installed qt5 to solve it

Answer (score 6):

For OSX, I had to

```
brew install qt
```

and then

```
sudo gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.7.2'
```

without sudo it would error

Answer (score 5):

## macOS Sierra 10.12, El Capitan 10.11 and Yosemite 10.10

**Install with either homebrew or macports**
**Homebrew**

Qt 5.5 is the last version of Qt that capybara-webkit will support. The Qt project has dropped the WebKit bindings from binary releases in 5.6.

**Install Qt 5.5 with homebrew:**

```
brew install qt@5.5
```

The Homebrew formula for qt55 is keg only which means binaries like qmake will not be symlinked into your /usr/local/bin directory and therefore will not be available for capybara-webkit.

To force Homebrew to symlink those binaries into your /usr/local/bin directory you can run:

```
brew link --force qt55
```

After running this command you should get the following output:

```
$ which qmake
/usr/local/bin/qmake
```

**Macports**

**Install qt5 with macports:**

```
sudo port install qt5 qt5-qtwebkit # It's not qt5-mac anymore.
```

The default location for qt5's qmake is /opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/qmake. If the qmake on path is different, you can indicate the correct one with QMAKE environment variable.

```
QMAKE=/opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/qmake gem install capybara-webkit
```

Answer (score 3):

For Debian & Ubuntu

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++ qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x`

You can find other ways to install Qt [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit)

Answer (score 2):

QT was the answer for me, thougtbot provide a comprehensive installation options here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Generally depending on where you have home brew, this worked for me:

```
brew update
brew install qt
gem install capybara-webkit
```

Answer (score 1):

On OSX Mavericks 10.9, qt5 does not install qmake.  [This](http://enriquecanals.com/blog/2013/11/05/Error-with-capybara-webkit-on-os-x-Mavericks/) post was the only thing that worked for me.

> Step 1: Download Qt 5.2.0-beta-1-clang [HERE](http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0-beta1/).
>
> Step 2: Install it and include the Src files.
>
> Step 3: Symlink qmake into your /bin directory from the location where you installed Qt. The default location is in your home directory. Open a shell and do something like:

```
 ln -s /Path/to/where/you/installed/Qt5.2/5.2.0-beta1/clang_64/bin/qmake /usr/local/bin/qmake
```

Then gem install capybara-webkit.

Comment: For me, having installed qt5 with homebrew, it was: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.1/bin/qmake /usr/local/bin/qmake`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Yosemite and following commands has fixed my issue.

```
brew install qt
brew linkapps qt
gem install capybara-webkit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the complete steps to install `Capybara-webkit` in all the OS

1. Install QT - http://qt-project.org/downloads

   `brew update
    brew install qt`
2. `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.1/bin/qmake /usr/local/bin/qmake`
3. `sudo port install qt4-mac-devel`

Reference:
[Capybara Installation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

For fedora

```
yum install qt-webkit-devel
export QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
gem install capybara-webkit
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get qt and capybara-webkit installed and working on OS X. I had to install Xcode so the build for

`gem install capybara-webkit`

would finish.

I also set this in my environment

`Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`

`brew install qt5` to get latest qt.

The docs for it say that it conflicts with qt4, so be sure to remove that first with

`brew uninstall [old qt]`

Then it needs to be symlinked with

`brew link --force qt5`

Comment: to make sure qt is installed run `which qmake` should return something like `/usr/local/bin/qmake`

Answer (score 0):

I've got error in my mac OS X 10.12, and this fixed the problem.

```
brew install qt5
brew link --force qt5
gem install capybara-webkit
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error on the second step:
```% brew link --force qt5
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.2... 
Error: Could not symlink Frameworks/Qt3DAnimation.framework
/usr/local/Frameworks is not writable.
```