# cant install capybara webkit gem

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, capybara

@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.14.2'
[sudo] password for jsnow: 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
```

cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.2/src/webkit_server.pro -spec linux-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server ) && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 3
Command 'make' failed

make  clean
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.2/src/webkit_server.pro -spec linux-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server ) && make -f Makefile.webkit_server clean
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-clean-ordered] Error 3

make
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.2/src/webkit_server.pro -spec linux-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server ) && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 3

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/capybara-webkit-0.14.2/gem_make.out

Comment: do you have qt installed?

Comment: yes this is what I get...

Comment: jsnow@ubuntu:~$ which qmake 
/usr/local/sbin/qmake

Comment: jsnow@ubuntu:~$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing gem capybara-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365764/error-installing-gem-capybara-webkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the development headers for webkit with qt.

The instructions are [in the wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit).

In debian unstable it worked installing the packages `libqtwebkit-dev qt4-qmake`